# How can i merge multiple plugin kdb files?

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I have created four liberty servers (Liberty1, Liberty2, Liberty3, Liberty4 as server names) and one **IBM HTTP Server** as front end. All my request are routing through the **IHS**. **SSL** has been installed and its between HTTP Server and Liberty1 server. I have generate merged Plugins of different Liberty Servers and propagate to **IHS**. Now my challenge is to merge the Plugin-cfg.kdb, pluging-cfg.rdb, plugin-cfg.sth file and copy it to the Webserver plugin folder for SSL to work on the Liberty servers. Could anyone provide me the commands to do the same. (Please not through ikeyman).

Answer (score 0):

You only need to merge the CA certificates in the *.kdb. Here's an example script that extracts all the signers and collects them in a new keystore:

https://github.com/covener/plugin-tools/blob/master/mergekdbs.sh

```
if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
  echo "$0 merged.kdb old1.kdb old2.kdb [old3.kdb...]"
  exit 1
fi

NEWKDB=$1
shift

if [ ! -f $NEWKDB ]; then
   gskcapicmd -keydb -create -db $NEWKDB -pw WebAS -stash
fi

DIR=`mktemp -d`

for OLDKDB in "$@"; do
gskcapicmd -cert -list -stashed -db $OLDKDB| grep ^\!| cut -d\! -f 2|sed -e s'/"//g'  \
| while read line; do
   rm -f "$DIR/$line"
   gskcapicmd -cert -extract -stashed -target "$DIR/$line" -label "$line" -db $OLDKDB
done
done

find $DIR -type f |
while read CA; do
   gskcapicmd -cert -add -db $NEWKDB -stashed -file "$CA" -label "`basename "$CA"`"
done
```

Comment: Note: uses a default password if a new keystore is specified as the first arg.

Comment: Tks for the timely help